# NInject complex injection with dynamic data

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have an algorithm to run, like this:

```cs
public interface IAlgorithm
{
    void Run();
}
```

It depends on the `IContainer` interface that looks like this:

```cs
public interface IContainer
{
    int Size();
}
```

The implemention of this interface needs some data gotten from UI

```cs
public class Container : IContainer
{
    private readonly List<int> _data;

    public Container(IEnumerable<int> data)
    {
        _data = new List<int>(data);
    }

    public int Size()
    {
        return _data.Count;
    }
}
```

Then the implementation of IAlgorithm might look like this:

```cs
public class Algorithm : IAlgorithm
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public Algorithm(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_container.Size());
    }
}
```

I want to implement this interface so that it's injectible via NInject (so I can use it as a constructor parameter for a ViewModel).

```cs
public interface IAlgorithmFactory
{
    IAlgorithm Create(IEnumerable<int> data);
}
```

The problem is: I need to be able to get the right instance of `IContainer` from the `Kernel` during the `Algorithm` construction. In the real-world situations the dependency graph of the algorithm is quite big and there is not one thing that needs to be created from the data, but 3 and these things are further dependencies of some other things.

My solution is that all classes that needs to be created from the data have the method called `Initialize`. The caller must initilize these serives before using other methods. That sounds like a bad practice.

In fact, the real code that I'm talking about can be seen [here](https://github.com/PatrikBak/GeoGen/blob/develop/GeoGen.Generator/GeneratorFactory.cs). Right now everything is injected as Singleton.

Is there some other way to inject those things via NInject?

Note: I already asked this question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361619/dependency-injection-with-runtime-data), from a design point of view. I think this is the better place to get the answer specifically about an NInject solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by using Ninject configuration, you can do it in this way:

```
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IContainer>()
            .To<Container>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("data",
                ctx => ctx.Request.ParentContext.Parameters
                    .Single(x => x.Name == "data")
                    .GetValue(ctx, null));
        kernel.Bind<IAlgorithm>().To<Algorithm>();
        kernel.Bind<IAlgorithmFactory>().ToFactory();

        var factory = kernel.Get<IAlgorithmFactory>();
        var algorithm = factory.Create(new List<int>() { 1 });
```

Here the `data` parmeter is taken from the factory method parameter and passed down to the `Container` constructor.